# Alias Logic in Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have always find problem while using alias. Actually I want to use table alias that means a complex type of alias. I am not sure if my requirement is right or I am doing in the right way it is suppose to but yet if you can clear my doubts on how we can select something using alias on a query would be much appreciated. Please ignore my english language.

This is the query

```
select * 
from TBL 
where lng_TaskId not in 
      (select lng_TaskId 
       from Mask_Tasks MT 
       inner join Mask_TaskCategories MC on MT.lng_TaskCatID = MC.lng_taskCatid 
                                         and MT.lng_MajEqId = MC.lng_MajEqId) TBL
```

So, I have a sub query which will run first to give me some ID's. Now I want to use it an alias and then want to select from this alias in my outer or main query. Can you please explain how to use alias in this way or any other better way to use an alias in SQL server. I will really be thankful to you.

Comment: If there is  no match, what do you expect to return from the query?  Sample data and desired results would really help convey what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you query were `IN` rather than `NOT IN`, then you can use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
select t.*, . . .
from TBL t CROSS APPLY
     (select lng_TaskId, . . .
      from Mask_Tasks MT inner join
           Mask_TaskCategories MC
           on MT.lng_TaskCatID = MC.lng_taskCatid and
              MT.lng_MajEqId = MC.lng_MajEqId
      where mt.lng_TaskId = t.lng_TaskId
     ) tt;
```

However, with `NOT IN` your request doesn't make sense.  There is no match, so any columns from the "subquery" would be `NULL`.

Note:  in the above, the ". . ." means that you can put in your own columns.  Also, the correlation in `tt` is a guess.  You should always qualify your column names so you -- and other people -- know what your query is doing.